# Apache/nginx fine grained (per file) permissions?

Tags: apache, authentication, permissions, authorization, nginx

Is it possible to set fine-grained permissions using either Apache or nginx? Given a large number of files and a large number of users, what's a good way to specify that each authenticated user only has access his/her own files?

```
user_a can access file_a_1, file_a_2
user_b can access file_b_1
user_c can access file_c_1, file_c2, file_c3, file_a_2
```

These are static, read-only files (for the most part). Imagine file-system like access control but with http. No web-dav; this is part of a web app; the images will display as part of the user's page in a browser. I want to make sure nobody else can see the image even if they can find the url for it.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh. Short of writing your own authentication handler, I doubt there is an easy way of accomplishing this, at least with Apache.

If [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) were an option, I would probably implement the security check in a PHP script and if everything checks out, add a [`X-LIGHTTPD-send-file`](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/X-LIGHTTPD-send-file) header to the response. This means that lighty will do all the file transfer without it going through PHP.

(A quick googling revealed that apache *should* support something like this with `X-sendfile`, but I was unable to get anything about this from the Apache documentation.)

edit: Apparently you can do a similar thing with Apache and [`mod proxy scgi`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_scgi.html).

Comment: andri, thanks, this seems like a good path. I remember reading something similar for nginx; I believe you can run a script and based on the result serve a file. Let me dig into that a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I realize I'm necroposting here, but just for future googlers,

Here's the analogous nginx option for andri's solution:

http://blog.kovyrin.net/2006/11/01/nginx-x-accel-redirect-php-rails/

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxXSendfile

...and the same thing for Apache, apparently:

http://tn123.ath.cx/mod_xsendfile/

Comment: Thanks for (necro-)posting this, I did google it, find it and your solution *did* help! Thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're looking to do.  Do these users need write permissions, or are the files read-only?  Are these static files?

Comment: Updated the question with clarification.